# Is it possible to connect azure databricks secret scope to a keyvault on other resource group

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-databricks

I have a common azure databricks resources in a shared resource group. For every customer i have different resource groups automated. Based on my design, My notebook need to read some keyvault variables from keyvaults created in other resource groups using databricks scope variables.

Is it possible to create such scope variables. I am finding errors.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to connect azure databricks secret scope to a keyvault on other resource group. Could you please share the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to connect Azure Databricks secret scope to a keyVault on other resource group.

Here is an example of creating secret scope to a KeyVault from another resource group.

[image]

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.